# Ajax requesting an API for data on a project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, fetch-api

I am busy with a private coding project right now, but can't seem to get my code to work properly.

I want to in essence, get data from my API and display it on to my HTML page, the data type is set to "jsonp" because of CORS errors (this was the only way I could debug it), anyone have an idea of how I can get this to return usable data for my project?

---

```
function fetch(){
"use strict";var url = "https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions?token=*my_unique_token*";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
         },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
    },
        done: function(data){
            console.log(data);
    },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
    }
    
    });
}
```

---

Edit:
This is a parsing problem, I cant get the code to log the success, I can see a response but its for my error log, but it doesn't show the success log, so the data is unusable.

Comment: Well do they support jsonp? `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');` is useless since that is a server header, not a clientside one.

Comment: Sounds like you need support from pandascore.co, not stackoverflow.com... They [seem to have pretty good documentation](https://developers.pandascore.co/doc/).

Comment: @epascarello the jsonp dataType was the only way I could get around CORS errors, the text data type as seen above doesn't stop the errors

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am fairly new to coding, also I have edited in what my actual problem is, I can see the data is there its just not logging correctly ( error logs )

Comment: Please read [ask]. We're not going to be able to help you diagnose an error if we don't know what the error is, right? So that should be step #1. But really, read [ask] and [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/215552)

Comment: You said "the data type is set to "jsonp" " but the code says "dataType: 'text',"

Comment: @Quentin I was trying something while coding, changed it back now, thanks for informing me

Comment: "I can see a response but its for my error log" — So what errors are reported?

Comment: My error log gives me an object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not try the vanilla fetch method?

```
const url = 'https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions?token=my_unique_token';
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

This code should handle parsing JSON data you receive from pandascore. Fetch is not available in IE11, but there should be some polyfills lying around on the web.

Comment: Just tried my code from above with my own token and got back and array with 50 objects .No need to set any request headers. Simply use the token and that is all.

The issue might be with the fact that you try to make the ajax call from your own localhost. If you run this code in the browser it will work fine.